# Spring Boot JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize error

Tags: java, mysql, json, spring-boot

```
{
    "timestamp": "2018-07-18T11:02:29.789+0000",
    "status": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "message": "JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of `com.springboot.sprinboot.model.Users` out of START_ARRAY token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `com.springboot.sprinboot.model.Users` out of START_ARRAY token\n at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]",
    "path": "/rest/users/"
}
```

That's Error Message

```
package com.springboot.sprinboot.resource;

import com.springboot.sprinboot.model.Users;
import com.springboot.sprinboot.repository.UsersRepository;
import org.apache.tomcat.util.http.parser.MediaType;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

import java.awt.*;
import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/rest/users")
public class UsersResource {

    @Autowired
    UsersRepository usersRepository;

    @GetMapping(value = "/all")
    public List<Users> getAll(){
        return usersRepository.findAll();

    }

    
     @PostMapping (value = "/load")
public List<Users> persist(@RequestBody final Users users){
    usersRepository.save(users);
    return usersRepository.findAll();
    }
}

UsersResource.java

package com.springboot.sprinboot.repository;

import com.springboot.sprinboot.model.Users;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface UsersRepository extends JpaRepository<Users, Integer> {
}
```

UsersRepository.java

```
package com.springboot.sprinboot.model;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Users {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "team_name")
    private String teamName;
    @Column (name = "salary")
    private Integer salary;

    public Users() {
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getTeamName() {
        return teamName;
    }

    public void setTeamName(String teamName) {
        this.teamName = teamName;
    }

    public Integer getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }

    public void setSalary(Integer salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }
}
```

Users.java

Summary;

At address (localhost:8080/rest/users/all), Get operation is running smoothly.
But when I try to create a new User with post at (localhost:8080/rest/users/load), I get error:

> "message": "JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of `com.springboot.sprinboot.model.Users` out of START_ARRAY token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `com.springboot.sprinboot.model.Users` out of START_ARRAY token\n at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]",

example json

```
[
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "omer",
        "teamName": "omr",
        "salary": 200
    }
]
```

---

## Solved

```
{      
        "name": "omer",
        "teamName": "omr",
        "salary": 200
}
```

everyone thank you, I was need can't add because id is primary key.

Comment: Can you also show the json that you are sending while saving?

Comment: can you post your json request. Seems that you send an array of users and not a single one. Change your json or your method to accept a list

Comment: My feeling is that your JSON is malformed.

Comment: You need to add your json to get the help

Comment: now, added json

Comment: While copying response of get request, there may be some space issue or some format issue. So that it is not taking request in exact format. When i write the request manually, issue resolved. Also i got the response.

Answer (score 6):

You should send a JSON similar to this

```
{
     "id": 1,
     "name": "omer"
    ........ 

}
```

Most probably you are using `[` instead of `{` or maybe both

Comment: yes, i was use both,i need use just " { ", but the source of this error is that id is the primary key.