# Jackson InvalidFormatException: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.util.UUID` from String

Tags: jackson, uuid, spring-restcontroller

Am using Spring boot with a Rest Controller. I have a `@PostMapping` with a `@RequestBody` having object that has id of type `UUID`. When I am trying to test my post request from Postman I get the following error.

JSON parse error:

> Cannot deserialize value of type `java.util.UUID` from String "4be4bd08cfdf407484f6a04131790949": UUID has to be represented by standard 36-char representation; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.util.UUID` from String "4be4bd08cfdf407484f6a04131790949": UUID has to be represented by standard 36-char representation

I read in some post that talked about invalidFormatException but with a different data type that need to write some kind of Adapter. How can I resolve this for the UUID? Thanks in advance for your input.

```
@PostMapping(value = "/save_order")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
public void postOrder(@RequestBody Order order) {
...

public class Order {
@Id
private UUID dstId;
....
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Never mind, I searched around and was able to resolve the issue. Below is the solution.

So basically the solution was to remove the ID from the JSON that I was using for the request body. The Json that I was using earlier had dstId as the first key, removing it resolved my error.

```
{
 "dstId":"4be4bd08cfdf407484f6a04131790949",
  ...
}
```

Also I realized that the root cause was that the data I was using above is not a valid UUID. Using a valid UUID in it's place worked, for example 
"dstId": "110841e3-e6fb-4191-8fd8-5674a5107c33

The post that helped me to figure out [Spring Boot JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51400584/spring-boot-json-parse-error-cannot-deserialize-error)